# javascript or jquery - get the last 2 characters of href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the last 2 characters from the href of a link and place them into a string.

I'm sure this is fairly simple but I seem to be struggling.

Here's the link

```
<a href="../mypage/?code=bb">test</a>
```

I need to grab the "bb" part of the href.

Comment: Does this really make sense? Will the URL always be exactly in that form?

Comment: The URL will always end with a 2 letter code, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$(function() {      
    var res = $('a').attr('href').split(/=/)[1]
    alert(res);
});
```

This will not grab the last two character, but everything after the `=` sign which works probably more generic. And even if `the <center> cannot hold`, regex could look like

```
$(function() {      
   var href = $('a').attr('href'),
   res  = /\\?code=(\w+)/.exec(href);

   alert(res[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Presuming `link` is a reference to the element:

```
var chars = link.href.substr(-2);
```

If you need to get the reference to the link, it is best to give the link an ID attribute, e.g. `<a href="../mypage/?code=bb" id="myLink">`, where `myLink` is something that describes the link's purpose.  You can then do this:

```
var chars = document.getElementById('myLink').href.substr(-2);
```

Finally, if what you want is the `code` parameter from your link, it may be best to parse the URL into parts.  If there is a chance that your URL may be more complex that what you've shown, you should do real URL parsing.  As Rahul has pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668422/javascript-or-jquery-get-the-last-2-characters-of-href/4668470#4668470) there are some [jQuery plugins that perform this function](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object).

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = $('a').attr('href');
var last2char = href.substr(href.length-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try for some [**querystring plugins**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) which might be a better option.